# How to use subroutines in fortran 95?

Tags: fortran, subroutine, fortran95

I wrote this code, but I don't know why it's not working. I think it mostly is because of misusing subroutines. I know what is the format of subroutine, but don't know what's wrong with this. Can anyone debug this code for me? thanks.

```
PROGRAM AKI
IMPLICIT NONE 
INTEGER:: i,j,k,l,m,n
REAL :: R2,R1,dteta,dr
REAL ,DIMENSION (0:100) :: teta,r
REAL,DIMENSION(0:100,0:100) :: x,y

CALL SETUP
CALL GRID
CALL SAVING

PAUSE
END PROGRAM



SUBROUTINE SETUP
REAL , DIMENSION (0:100) :: teta,r
R2 = 10
R1 = 5
dr = (R2 - R1) / 9

r(1) = 5
DO i = 1,9
    r(i+1) = r(i) + dr
END DO
RETURN
END


SUBROUTINE GRID

REAL , DIMENSION(0:100) :: teta,r

REAL , DIMENSION(0:100,0:100) :: x,y
dteta = (2 * 3.1415)/9
teta(1) = 0
DO j= 1 , 9
    teta(j+1) = teta (j) + dteta
END DO

DO i = 1 , 10
    DO j = 0 , 10
        x(i,j) = r(i)*cos(teta(j))
        y(i,j) = r(i)*sin(teta(j))
    END DO
END DO

RETURN
END

SUBROUTINE SAVING
REAL , DIMENSION(0:100,0:100) :: x,y
OPEN( 1, file= "solution.dat")
DO i = 1,10
    DO j = 1,10

    WRITE(1, *) x(i,j),y(i,j)
    END DO
END DO
CLOSE(1)

RETURN
END
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow; you'll get better answers if you're clearer about your problem.  What output are you expecting, and what did you get instead?  In what part of the code have you determined the problem to be?  Can you pose a more specific problem focusing on just that part of the code?  This article - [ask] - gives more suggestions on how to pose a question that will get the information you need.

Comment: @JonathanDursi thanks. Maybe I need to take a look around to get familiar with the website. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you are not passing your arguments to the subroutine.  Your calls to `SETUP`, `GRID`, and `SAVING` are all using their own locally scoped variables.   This is further confused by your use of implicit typing that allows you to use variables that you did not explicitly declare.  Try this:

```
subroutine SETUP(r)
   implicit none
   REAL , DIMENSION (0:100), intent(out) :: r
   real :: R2, R1, dr

   R2 = 10
   R1 = 5
   dr = (R2 - R1) / 9

   r(1) = 5
   DO i = 1,9
      r(i+1) = r(i) + dr
   END DO
   RETURN
END subroutine
```

and call it as

```
call SETUP(r)
```

You will need to make similar adjustments to your other subroutines.

If you alternatively want to use these variables without passing them to each subroutine, you can use host scope and include the subroutines in your main program after a `contains` statement and before the `end program` statement.  In that case, you would not declare them in the subroutines at all, you would just use them.

Comment: could you please explain more about how to use subroutines without passing arguments to them? I want to use global variables.

Comment: @Rasoolll Fortran doesn't really have a true global scope.  In the F77 days "global" variables were often handled by including a file with common blocks in each file that needed access to the "global" variables.  Today you are better off using modules to contain the variables you want to be "global" and then using that module in each subroutine that needs access to the variables.